# Getting all dates format with regex with explanations

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

I invented an exercise for myself and now kinda struggle to understand how the regex works. I want a solution with correct explanation so I can clear some my trepidation about regex. I am trying to all dates in my string; month, year, and day. Here my string and what I have done:

```
   date_str="je suis ne le 23 Oct 2002,\
   I was born on 23 October 2002,\
   just Oct 23 2002,\
   ye gusta October 23 2002"

  re.findall(r' \d{2}\ ?[a-zA-Z]* \d{2,4}', date_str)

  #Out[162]:
  [' 23 Oct 2002', ' 23 October 2002', ' 23 2002', ' 23 2002']
```

I have also looked at some codes and the question mark and colon were  sometimes used to get say that a group occurs 0 or 1 time. I do not know what the colon means. But I have tried something else that also gives me the same result as the above.

```
  re.findall(r' (?:\d{2})\ ?[a-zA-Z]*\ \d{2,4}', date_str)
  #Out[162]:
  [' 23 Oct 2002', ' 23 October 2002', ' 23 2002', ' 23 2002']
```

First, I am not able to get the last two dates but I am not able to understand whats the colon all about since I can't even see it in my string. Plus why can't I get the question mark outside the group? It gives me error

Comment: i shall..uh.. just leave this here. https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a little bit to specific. Anyways, maybe it helps you out.

```
import re

date_str="je suis ne le 23 Oct 2002,\
I was born on 23 October 2002,\
just Oct 23 2002,\
ye gusta October 23 2002"
a = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d+\s\d{2,4}|\d{1,2}\s*?[a-zA-Z]*\s*\d{2,4}', date_str)
print(a)
```

## ['23 Oct 2002', '23 October 2002', 'Oct 23 2002', 'October 23 2002']

> "
>       [a-zA-Z]+\s+\d+\s\d{2,4}|\d{1,2}\s*?[a-zA-Z]*\s*\d{2,4}
>       "
>       gm
>       1st Alternative [a-zA-Z]+\s+\d+\s\d{2,4}
>       Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z]+
>       + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>       a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
>       A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
>       \s+
>       matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>       + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>       \d+
>       matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>       + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>       \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>       \d{2,4}
>       matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>       {2,4} Quantifier — Matches between 2 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>       2nd Alternative \d{1,2}\s*?[a-zA-Z]*\s*\d{2,4}
>       \d{1,2}
>       matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>       {1,2} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>       \s*?
>       matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>       *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)